# How can I replace header/footer values with templateProcessor at PhpWord?

Tags: php, templates, docx, phpword

I´ve got a docx template and I want to change the values of the headers and the footers using templateProccessor. I have done it with the simple text, but I don´t know how to do it for the headers and footers.

This is the code that I have:

```
    // Creating the new document...
    $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('../Template.docx');

    //Set headers and footers


    //set value
    $templateProcessor->setValue('title', 'Test');

    //Triplicate block
    $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('firstblock', 3, true, true);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('firstname#1', 'John');
    $templateProcessor->setValue('lastname#1', 'Doe');
    $templateProcessor->setValue('firstname#2', 'John');
    $templateProcessor->setValue('lastname#2', 'Doe');
    $templateProcessor->setValue('firstname#3', 'John');
    $templateProcessor->setValue('lastname#3', 'Doe');
    //Set image
    $templateProcessor->setImageValue('logo', array('path' => '../img/logo.png',
        'width' => 100, 'height' => 100));
    $templateProcessor->saveAs('test.docx');
```